# lstlisting and bold keywords

Tags: lstlisting

I have the following MWE for SQL typesetting. What doesn't work for me and for which I need help are two things:

1. I would like to add "SUCH AS" as a keyword (or make it bold in the text without defining it as a keyword); and
2. I need "domain" not to be bold, but it insists in typesetting it bold even when I include it in `deletekeywords`. Don't know what is happening there.

   ```
   \documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

   \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} 
   \usepackage{listings}

   \lstset{language=SQL,basicstyle=\ttfamily,keywordstyle=\bfseries,
     showspaces=false,showstringspaces=false, 
     morekeywords={*,IF,DEFINE,OPTIONS, SERVER, MENTIONS, SUCH THAT}, 
     deletekeywords={domain}, mathescape=true, aboveskip=0pt, belowskip=6pt}

   \begin{document}   
   \begin{lstlisting} 
   FROM Relation SUCH THAT domain-condition 
   \end{lstlisting}
   \end{document}
   ```

Would appreciate any help. Here is what comes out when I typeset it.

[image]

Comment: Sorry -- I don't know why the MWE is coming out this way... I did enter it as a code fragment but it is not being typeset as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get rid of the `domain` keyword, you have to spell it in uppercase in `deletekeywords` because that's how it is defined in the [drivers file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/lstdrvrs.pdf).

Additionally, spaces may not occur in keywords. You could perhaps make the space a letter or other character and define keywords based on that, but this would likely cause problems with the word-breaking mechanism.

An easy solution is to use the `literate` option to replace each literal occurrence of `SUCH THAT` by the same string with the corresponding style being applied.

In sum, the new listings setup would look like this (modified options are highlighted):

```
    \lstset{
        language=SQL,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        keywordstyle=\bfseries,
        showspaces=false,
        showstringspaces=false,
        morekeywords={*,IF,DEFINE,OPTIONS,SERVER,MENTIONS},
        deletekeywords={DOMAIN},
        mathescape=true,
        aboveskip=0pt,
        belowskip=6pt,
        literate={SUCH\ THAT}{\bfseries SUCH\ THAT}{9}
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. I'll try these.